# firestore collection, retrieving field values to store and use

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to access my Firestore collection and iterate through all documents to extract on the `valenceId` field in each document.

I have tried following but it is showing an error "can not retrieve `valenceId` of undefined". I have also tried using an observable but cannot extract data. This is new to me so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code I've tried:

```js
doc:Item;
doc_comments: Array<number>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.db.collection('entry').doc<Item> 
     ('doc_Id').valueChanges().subscribe( data =>{
        this.doc=data;
        this.doc_comments= Array(data.Ids);
        console.log('doc_comments', this.doc_comments);
      }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, is calling `.valueChanges()` function on single document called 'doc_Id'... If you want to iterate through all documents in your collection, just use

```
this.db.collection('diaryEntry').valueChanges().subscribe(
// your logic goes here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After `valueChanges` and `subscribe` calls you will get an array of objects containing the data you want to collect, so i'm using `forEach` inside to iterate through it and it works for me.

Note that `this.doc` is not an array in your example so it will save the last one and i do not think that what you aimed for.

```
doc:Item;
doc_comments: Array<number>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.db.collection('entry').valueChanges().subscribe( data_array =>{
        data_array.forEach(doc => {
            this.doc = data;
            this.doc_comments = Array(data.Ids);
        })
        console.log('doc_comments', this.doc_comments);
      }
   );
}
```